# How to render offscreen content with RenderTargetBitmap in UWP?

Tags: .net, uwp, rendertargetbitmap

I'm trying to render the contents of a `UserControl` to frames the create a video in 1080p, so I created a set the size to my control accordingly:

```
RenderControl.Width = 1920;
RenderControl.Height = 1080;
```

After setting the size, I execute this code:

```
var rendertargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
await rendertargetBitmap.RenderAsync(RenderControl);
```

The problem is that **this will only render the contents that are onscreen**. I want my contents to be captured even in they're offscreen.

How can I do it? This limitation is really inconvenient. I cannot force users to maximize (or resize) the hosting Window to render a video. It feels really hacky.

Comment: Most probably you can't do that. Consider creating your own UIs with Composition API to have the control of what will be drawn in those UIs.